# Subsubsection displaced!

Tags: sectioning

For some reason my subsubsections appear outside my page! How do I fix this problem?

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ok, I will try.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP remarked the error himself and could solve it

Answer (score 1):

I found the error, but now I just feel really stupid! It's a template I borrowed from a friend, and in the code (where I did not suspect it to be) I found

```
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{-2cm}
```

I have no idea why this is desirable, but never the less, the problem is solved.

Comment: Templates are most times not desirable ;-)